# Fill Holes of AForge.net not working

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, gesture-recognition, aforge

I am trying to smooth the morphological operation. I have already done 4*4 erosion and 4*4 dilation(I tried my best to achieve best on erosion and dilation) on an image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPhXN.jpg). Then i have detect largest blob to filter out noises. Then my next step is to smooth morphological operation for the image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjKg7.jpg) *so that i can fill the gap inside the image contour*. **I used the following code segment to fill the gap using aforge. But this method returns nothing**.

```
public Bitmap fillGap(Bitmap image)
        {

            FillHoles filter = new FillHoles();
            filter.MaxHoleHeight = 5;
            filter.MaxHoleWidth = 5;
            filter.CoupledSizeFiltering = false;
            filter.Apply(image);
            return image;
        }
```

What is my next step to correct it?

[image: Skin Detected Image]
[image: Morphological Image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/), the `Apply` method leaves the source image unchanged. Either replace the last two lines in your method with:

```
return filter.Apply(image);
```

or use the `ApplyInPlace` method instead of `Apply`:

```
filter.ApplyInPlace(image);
return image;
```

BTW, are `MaxHoleHeight` and `MaxHoleWidth` set to large enough values?

Comment: Still function is not working. Is there any image foramt (8bbp) is missing?

Comment: According to the `FillHoles` class documentation, the image is required to be 8bpp binary, yes. I really do not have too much experience with this library myself, put to be on the safe side perhaps you can create a clone of the source image and apply the `FillHoles` filter on the cloned image? `var clonedImg = Image.Clone(image, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);`. I am not sure that this is sufficient for making the image susceptible to the `FillHoles` filter, but at least it is worth a try?

Comment: Perhaps you also need to apply the `Threshold` filter prior to the `FillHoles` filter. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11005067/650012) SO question.

Comment: I got it to work fine on the second image, but only by thresholding it.  Now, that's with the JPEG posted here, which as a result of the compression process, had pixels that were not true black or true white.  Are you compressing it inside your application, or saving it as JPEG and reloading it before applying FillHoles?