# Aforge fill holes filter result in black image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, aforge

I'm trying use Aforge library for filling holes in the resulting binary image, the problem is I'm getting a BLACK image as a result instead of the filled image.
Your assistance is highly appreciated.

```
Bitmap bitImage = (Bitmap)pic.Image;
Bitmap bm = Convert(bitImage);
FillHoles filter = new FillHoles();
filter.CoupledSizeFiltering = true;
// apply the filter
pictureBox1.Image = filter.Apply(bm);

public Bitmap Convert(Bitmap bit)
{

    Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    // apply the filter
    Bitmap bm = filter.Apply(bit);
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Post your image, so we can help you

Comment: I think the image is required to be pure black-and-white, i.e. binary, before you can use the `FillHoles` filter. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11005067/650012) for details on binarization.